# MongoDB + NextJS docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, next.js

I'm trying to run my NextJS project and call my MongoDB docker container but It doesnt work.
I need to create a Login and Register system with mongo, I don't know what is wrong

I've this error in console:

```
Iniciando processo de criação de usuário...
ok find or create user
ok connect to database
Erro ao criar usuário: MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/root/workspace/Anhanguera_Tuba/anhanguera/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:277:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:569:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:512:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Unknown',
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    commonWireVersion: 0,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null
  },
  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

mongoConnect.js

```
// lib/mongoConnect.js

import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI;
const client = new MongoClient(uri, { useUnifiedTopology: true });

export async function connectToDatabase() {
  console.log("ok connect to database");
  if (!client.topology || !client.topology.isConnected()) {
    await client.connect();
  }
  console.log(client)
  return client;
}

export async function findOrCreateUser(email, password) {
  console.log("ok find or create user");
  const client = await connectToDatabase();
  const db = client.db();
  console.log(db)
  const usersCollection = db.collection('usuarios');
  console.log("ok collection and db");

  const user = await usersCollection.findOne({ email });

  if (!user) {
    const newUser = {
      email,
      password, // Você deve armazenar a senha como um hash, não em texto simples.
    };
    console.log("ok new user")
    await usersCollection.insertOne(newUser);
    console.log('Usuário criado com sucesso:', newUser); // Adicione esta linha para depurar
    return newUser;
  }

  console.log('Usuário encontrado:', user); // Adicione esta linha para depurar
  return user;
}

export async function verifyUser(email, password) {
  const client = await connectToDatabase();
  const db = client.db();

  const existingUser = await db.collection('usuarios').findOne({ email });

  if (!existingUser) {
    return null;
  }

  // Você pode usar a biblioteca bcrypt para comparar senhas criptografadas
  // const passwordsMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.password);
  // if (!passwordsMatch) {
  //   return null;
  // }

  // Para fins de demonstração, estamos comparando as senhas diretamente
  if (existingUser.password !== password) {
    return null;
  }

  return existingUser;
}

export async function loginUser(email, password) {
  const user = await verifyUser(email, password);
  if (!user) {
    return null;
  }

  const token = jwt.sign({ email }, process.env.JWT_SECRET); // verifique se JWT_SECRET está definido e correto

  console.log('Token gerado:', token); // Adicione esta linha para depurar

  return token;
}
```

.env.local

`MONGODB_URI=mongodb://adm:123@localhost:27017/nextDB`

I've tried to change mongoURI, tried to verify my docker port but nothing works

Comment: Is your nextjs app also in a docker container?